# How to create root certificate authority using CLI? [OSX]

Tags: ssl

Hello I am trying to create root certificate authority for my own MITM proxy. Based on other tutorial I have used following command.

1. Generate a  private key

```sh
openssl genrsa -out cert.key 2048
```

2. Generate a certificate

```sh
openssl req -new -nodes -x509 -key cert.key -days 365 -out cert.crt
```

Now the problem is when i try to add to keychain it shows `Self Signed Root CA`. What i have found is other MITM proxy like proxyman generates cert that shows `Root Certificate Authority`. Here is screenshot which illustrate my point.

[image: On left side proxyman software shows root certificate authority on right side which i generated shows self signed root ca]

I know i can make certificate that shows `Root Certificate Authority` from Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Create a Certificate Authority.

However my goal is to create certificate programmatically so  I can generate certificate for other user easily.

Thanks

Comment: " so I can generate certificate for other user easily. " Then you need only once to create a root certificate and then all user certificates will be signed by this root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several searching i found following command works. I don't know why it works it would be helpful.

```
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key cert.key -subj "/CN=HELLO" -days 3650 -reqexts v3_req -extensions v3_ca -out ca.crt -config /usr/local/etc/openssl/openssl.cnf
```

It seem adding something related to v3_req fixes the issue.

Be sure to use latest version of openssl. I used homebrew to install openssl